# Get items from localStorage and export them

Tags: javascript, function, local-storage, refactoring

I have a function where it takes fields stored in state and returns them if they exist.

```
export const hasNameAndTokenSelector = (state) => {  
    const { fields } = baseInputsSelector(state);
    const hasName = !isNil(prop('name')(fields));
    const hasToken = !isNil(prop('token')(fields));
    
    return hasName && hasToken;
};
```

But now I need to use this same function to get items stored in localStorage.
I'm trying to do the following:

```
export const hasNameAndTokenSelector = (state) => {
    if (localStorage.getItem('inputs') !== null) {
      const localInputs = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('inputs'));
  
      const hasToken = localInputs[0].token;
      const hasName = localInputs[0].name;
  
      return hasName && hasToken;
    }
  };
```

The format of localInputs is:

```
{
   "name":"John Doe",
   "token":"string123-9882",
}
```

But it doesn't work, I believe it's because I need the state parameter and the return is inside an if, but I don't know the correct way to proceed.

**How should I get these stored items and return them?**  I need to use hasNameAndTokenSelector in another file.

Thanks!!

Comment: what is the format of `localInputs`?

Comment: @Georgy I edited the question with this information

Comment: _side note / code review_ ... since the function's name is `hasNameAndTokenSelector ` it is expected to always return a boolean value, neither once, as default, `undefined`, nor either of the string values `localInputs.token` / `localInputs.name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the above comment ...

> *"**... code review** ... since the function's name is `hasNameAndTokenSelector`  it is expected to always return a boolean value, neither once [the `undefined` default], nor either of the string values `localInputs.token` / `localInputs.name`."*

Thus, in order to solve the OP's original problem ...

> *"How should I get these stored items and return them?"*

... the OP's provided approach might be best refactored into two functions, one which fulfills the `getNameAndToken` part and another one which covers the already existing `hasNameAndToken` part ...

```
// `storedInputs` structure ...
// {
//   "name":"John Doe",
//   "token":"string123-9882",
// }
export const getNameAndToken = () => {
  const storedInputs = localStorage.getItem('inputs');

  return (storedInputs !== null)
    && JSON.parse(storedInputs)
    || {};
};
export const hasNameAndToken = () => {
  const { name, token } = getNameAndToken();
  return !!(name && token);
};


// usage in other modules
import { getNameAndToken/*, hasNameAndToken*/ } from '/'

const { name, token } = getNameAndToken();
```

Comment: Thank you!! I need to use this in a decorator file, like this: 
  connectify({
    hasNameAndToken: hasNameAndTokenSelector,
  })

Comment: @CodeG ... this already might be another subject / topic / question. If both until now provided answers did help solving the OP's original question, this subject is closed. In case the OP struggles applying the here provided solution, the OP needs to open another question with a carefully provided description of the new challenge.

Comment: @CodeG ... see my two cents on [*Get value from localStorage and use in decorator file*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70761991/get-value-from-localstorage-and-use-in-decorator-file#comment125097259_70761991)

Answer (score 0):

If you `localInputs` format is an object

```
{
   "name":"John Doe",
   "token":"string123-9882",
}
```

You should just take a property from this object, not from `localInputs[0]`:

```
const hasToken = localInputs.token;
const hasName = localInputs.name;
```

Comment: And how can I export the return to use elsewhere?

Comment: as usual, `import { hasNameAndTokenSelector } from '...'` and then use it as a regular function `hasNameAndTokenSelector()`